# What to do once you've edited a gemspec file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I downloaded the latest file from github, edited the .gemspec file to require a gem I need; what do I then do to be able to use the gem? Do I have to bundle it with bundler to be able to use it?

Sorry if dumb question, but so confused right now... can't find much info especially on Rapidfire...

Comment: it's your gem? do you want to publish a new version? do you want to use it locally? do you want to use it in your Gemfile?

Comment: Not my gem, t's Rapidfire - but in order to get Devise working, I need to add the dependency (i think) but not sure how to do it

Comment: did you forked the Rapidfire repository?

Comment: Ah, I haven't - I've downloaded the repository and edited the gemspec file, is this wrong?

Comment: I've added a second answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to [fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) the repository.
2. Clone the **forked repository** and edit the gemspec: `git clone git@github.com:code-mancers/rapidfire.git`
3. Commit your changes: `git add .; git commit -m "whatever"`
4. Push your changes: `git push origin master`
5. Edit the your project's Gemfile pointing the **forked gem**: `gem 'rapidfire', github: 'your-user/rapidfire', branch: 'master'`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help -- very clear and precise, it helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

`gem build path-of-the-gemspec-file`

Then

`gem install path-of-generated-gem-file`

For example:

In the root path of your gem, you can do:

`gem build my-gem.gempsec`

Then:

`gem install my-gem-0.1.0.gem`

To see if the gem was installed:

`gem list | grep my-gem`